# Changing heap and stack size from Play2 with scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

how can i change jvm configuration i.e. heap and stack size in a Play framework2 application with Scala

> activator run -Xms1G -Xmx2G -server

i have tried this command but jconsole  shows that heap size has not changed

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are Java switches; in Scala prefix them with `-J`, namely  `-J-Xms1G` and `-J-Xmx2G`.

**Edit**

For setting such options in `build.sbt` you must [enable a new jvm forking](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html) ,

```
fork in run := true
```

and specify the options for instance like this,

```
javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-Xms1G", "-Xmx2G")
```

Comment: is there any way of doing it from my build.sbt file? because with this i have to give stack size explicitly every time i want to run the project

Comment: it does not work for me with build.sbt , jconsole shows no change

Comment: @M.AhsenTaqi with -J ?